# Variable Gravity, how long in each?

Tags: gravity, health, artificial-gravity

Centrifugal force can be used to simulate gravity in space vehicles.

Assume the "gravity" in our space vehicle can provide environments ranging from 2 gravities to none (micro), either by changing locations on a large vehicle or by changing the spin of a smaller vehicle.

Sleeping in low gravity might be more comfortable, and if you are spending a lot of time in low gravity, exercising in higher gravity might get you more benefit in a shorter time.

If I have the option to very my gravity at will, what minimum and/or maximum time limits should I set per day?

Related:

- [Do you need a mattress on the Moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4643/109)
- [How do astronauts sleep in zero G?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10407/109)

Comment: You ask *the coolest, most intriguing questions!*

Comment: A healthy astronaut preparing on Earth for his next space flight would sleep for about 8 hours, do paper work at his desk for about 6 hours and do exercises for about 4 hours. Bedrest and sitting will not train his muscles and bones, but standing, walking, running and other sports will do. Therefore he should do exercises under artificial gravity for about 4 hours.

Comment: @uhoh thank you, they bounce around in my mind, and they end up here.

Comment: It's a pity we know next to nothing about long-term impact on human body of anything within the range between microgravity and 1g (excluding the range edges). AFAIR there were some studies in >1g centrifuge, but we know nearly nothing about long-term living in lunar or martian gravity. It's a very interesting question but I'm afraid, unanswerable currently.

Comment: @SF. answers to [How would travel to Mars without artificial gravity affect a crew's initial experience in Mars gravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16586/12102) support that as well.